# Sum of independent normal distribution signal sequence always bigger than 0 at each period

Tags: mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution

I was wondering if I could get some help with understanding this problem.
Suppose at each period you receive a random amount of money that follows normal distribution $N(0, 1)$. If the total money you've received is less than zero, you die at some period. I want to get the probability of survival at period $t$.

For two-period case,

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathbf{1}(x_{1}>0) \mathbf{1}(x_{1}+x_{2}>0) \phi(x_{1})\phi(x_{2})\; dx_{1} dx_{2}
$$
where $\phi$ is the pdf of the normal distribution. It becomes
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathbf{1}(x_{1}>0) \phi(x_{1}) \big{(}1-\Phi(-x_{1})\big{)} dx_{1}
$$
where $\Phi$ is cdf of the distribution. Finally,
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}  \phi(x_{1})\big{(}1-\Phi(-x_{1})\big{)}dx_{1}
$$

First, I wondered if, although it involves an erf function, there is a known closed-form solution for the above formula. Second, I wanted to generalise the above formula to $t$ periods, so I tried for the three-period case. Following the same procedure, I get the following:

$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} \phi(x_{1}) \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathbf{1}(x_{1}+x_{2}>0)  \big{(} 1-\Phi(-x_{1}-x_{2}) \big{)} \phi(x_{2}) dx_{2} dx_{1}. 
$$

I also wondered if there could be any way to leave only one integration with respect to $x_{1}$.

Comment: The rv $X_1+X_2$ remains a Normal rv.